# create array based on attr("id")

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I'm creating an @mention user in a contenteditiable div. The user onclick sends a selected userid to the contenteditible div before submitting it to the server

```
<div id='"+userid+"' class='userid' style='display:none;'></div>
```

Users can select more than one user to mention, but it will only ever send the first selected userid within the contenteditible to POST to my server side code.

How would I be able to change the below code so it sends all userids within the `#commentingcontents."+streamidcontent` . Is it possible to make the below an array?

```
    var userid = $(this).children("#commentingcontents."+streamidcontent).find(".userid").attr("id");
```

I looked at the JQUERY forum for inspiration on this matter but couldn't get the result I was after.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/attribute-values-into-an-array

Comment: You can store anything into an array. But your question lacks enough substance. What is your problem? What code have you tried?

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/attribute-values-into-an-array It would seem someone had the same question, I tried this method and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: no... What did YOU do... Im not concerned about other peoples work, this isnt how Stackoverflow works, we dont work to help you snarf other peoples code..

Comment: Excuse me? I'm not 'Snarfing' other peoples work. I'm showing you what I have found that relates to my question. And not being able to work it out, I came here for help. 
Someone has helped me below and I'll be happy enough to try his methods with the lack of substance he received from me.and my question, which I feel is pretty informative on what I 'd like to do.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place your selector result in an array

```
var my_array = $(this).children("#commentingcontents."+streamidcontent).find('.userid');
```

create an array to hold all of the user_ids

```
var user_id_array = [];
```

loop through each element in my_array

```
$.each( my_array, function( i, val ) {
    var user_id = $(val).attr('id');
    user_id_array.push(user_id);
});
```

Comment: See I was just reading this too. And I will try your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: A minor tweak by wrapping the val to make it Jquery object `$(val).attr('id');` and it works. Thank you for your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't test it before I submitted the answer, I am glad I can be of help, I will edit the initial answer.

Comment: Thank you @MackProgramsalot you did well.